# Gantt chart is not drawn and give "! LaTeX Error: Environment gantt undefined."

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, environments, landscape, pgfgantt

I am writing a report for FYP in Ubuntu 13.10 in TexMaker, with document class and use different files use for chapters. I write the code below in the chapter1.tex for draw a gantt chart

```
\documentclass{Thesis}
\usepackage{gantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{gantt}[xunitlength=1cm,fontsize=\large,titlefontsize=\large,drawledgerline=true]{13}{32}
\begin{ganttitle}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{September}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{October}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{November}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{December}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{January - 14}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{February}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{March}}{4}
  \titleelement{\Large \textbf{April}}{4}

\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle}
\titleelement{\LARGE \textbf{Weeks}}{32}
\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
  \numtitle{1}{1}{4}{1}
\end{ganttitle}
\ganttbar{Litreature Review}{2}{17}
\ganttbar{Project Plan}{5}{10}
\ganttbar{Field Survey}{15}{3}
\ganttbar{Data Collection}{20}{3}
\ganttbar{Database Design}{15}{5}
\ganttbar{Framework Design}{}{}
\ganttbar{Prototype}{}{}
\ganttbar{Implementation}{}{}
\ganttbar{Testing}{}{}
\ganttbar{Deployment}{}{}
\end{gantt}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

and I use packages in my main.tex file, but I got these errors when I run my main.tex file,

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment gantt undefined.
```

Comment: Perhaps you should load `pgfgantt` rather than `gantt`.

Comment: This is working for me, but it display on a single page how could I print it in between the page under section and subsection.

Comment: Perhaps adding a `\section` and `\subsection` before the first `gantt` environment? However this is another question; if you don't mind I would close the current question as it appears to be a typo in loading the package.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in loading the pgfgantt package.

Comment: Package problem is solved now, but my gantt chart is go beyond the page boundry, can anyone help me about this problem.